# Create new S3 class methods in R

Tags: r, class, methods, package

I'm writing a package in which I would like to create a new generic method, called "analyze", which do different things according to the argument class. Similar to `print` that has `print.lm`, `print.aov` etc.

In the R folder of my package, I created two files, "analyze.lm" and "analyze.aov" that contain eponym functions. However, if I run `analyze(fit)` on an `lm` object, it does nothing because R only recognizes `analyze.lm` and not the root function ("analyze" only).

I've tried adding an "analyze.R" file, which either contained `setMethod()` (but that errored), `setGeneric("analyze", function(x) attributes(x))` (but that did not solve the issue) or an `analyze()` function that prints "NULL". However, if I then run `analyze(fit)` on an `lm` object, in prints NULL instead of running the `analyze.lm` class method.

How could I create a generic method, similar to base `print`, that behaves differently according to argument class, and than I maintained split in different files (analyze.lm.R, analyze.aov.R etc.). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a generic function like this:

```
analyze <- function(object, ...){
    UseMethod("analyze")
}
```